# I am looking for a Gulp addon that will concat CSS files

Tags: css, gulp, less

Before you point me to the obvious gulp-concat-css let me elaborate.

I want to use gulp to concat a number of CSS files (or LESS files) which may have conflicting styles within them. I therefore wish to have gulp concat those files in a way that removes conflicting styles by overriding them based on the order that I concat if that makes sense.

Does anyone know of an addon that will do this? Maybe Gulp does it by default, in which case, how?

Thankyou.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat Does concatenating, and http://postcss.org/ has tools for post processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing of modularity is that every module has its own purpose.

So has concatenating the purpose of bringing things together and for 'removing duplicates' there is another module.

Post css contains tons of extensions you can use to post process your css. A list of options to choose from:

- [Css nano](http://cssnano.co/optimisations/discardDuplicates/)
- [gulp-dedupe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dedupe)
- another one: https://github.com/ben-eb/postcss-discard-duplicates

Css nano is pretty popular since it is also used by webpack2, so i think this would be your best bet if you want a popular and supported module.